# underline the the whole text of pdf table using itextsharp.text.pdf in .net framework 3.5 and c#

Tags: c#, .net, itext

I am creating a pdf table in my .net framework 3.5. I am trying to fully underline the text of my table like this:

Acc. Name    Bank    Acc. No.    Address

---

But I want the gap between the text and the line to be reduced because as soon as I add a new cell the gap increases.

And I want the output to be like this:

### Acc. Name    Bank    Acc. No.    Address

Please help me out on this.

Comment: add one row between these two rows and give it height.

Comment: It would help if you created a sample image that explained what you were looking to do.